# Different download speeds in Ifstat and Chrome

Tags: networking, chromium, downloads

I am downloading a file in Chromium and in parallel running Ifstat (a network-monitoring app). It's the only file I'm downloading.

The two programs show varying different speeds, and never the same, why's that?

Answer (score 0):

One of the things that can cause a discrepancy is the server where the file is hosted. So if the host server is slow then it will take longer to download.

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question. I'm asking why Ifstat shows a different speed from chrome, not why it takes longer to download.